# Simulate Google Maps Markers placement with a JavaScript class using setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, setinterval

I want to create a class in JavaScript by the following description.

This class is part of a simulation of truck movement on a route using Google Maps. What I want is to use setInterval in a class method as if it were a function, to be able to simulate many markers after repeatedly instantiating the object with different parameters.

```
class RouteMarker { 
    constructor(marker,pointsArray,i) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.pointsArray = pointsArray;
        this.i=i;
    }
    main() {        
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){this.myTimer}, 7000);
    }
    myTimer() {
        alert('o');
        this.setPostionM(this.i);
        this.i++; 
    }
    setPostionM(key) {     
        this.marker.setPosition(this.pointsArray[key]);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get the desired behavior if you call the `myTimer` function in `main`? I.e. `this.myTimer()`, not just `this.myTimer`.

Comment: You are not calling myTimer since it is missing the `() and if you did it still would not work because of what `this` refers too.  `console.log(this)`

Comment: I don't think you even need the anonymous function in there. try `setInterval(myTimer, 7000);`. From the looks of your code, myTimer doesn't seem to be a member function, so `this` probably breaks your code.

Comment: use setInterval(this.myTimer.bind(this), 7000);

Comment: @juvian I don't think that would work. `myTimer` is *not* a member function in the given code. And if it was, `setInterval(this.myTimer, 7000)` would suffice, the extra `this` would be ignored.

Comment: Tholle I did what you told me and this error appeared: Uncaught TypeError: this.myTimer is not a function

Comment: @Distjubo all methods are inside RouteMarker class. Using setInterval(this.myTimer, 7000) would make the scope be window when the function runs and this.setPostionM(this.i); wouldn´t work

Comment: @juvian Ah, didn't notice the extra braces around the whole class. OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code was quite there.**

---

Quick rundown:

- fixed some small things in your code, mainly formatting
- made sure that, when the `.myTimer()` function runs over all the points, it will stop itself (`this._intervalId`).
- shorten the `7000` millisecond interval to `1000` for quick demonstration purposes
- the `.myTimer()` function will call `alert()` with the current index (`this.i`)
- created a mocker class `MockMarker`, that's just simply a working placeholder for the Google Maps API, so you can run the sample code here.
- the `MockMarker` logs out the current, given position

```js
class RouteMarker { 
    constructor(marker, pointsArray, i) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.pointsArray = pointsArray;
        this.i = i;
    }
    
    main() {
        this._intervalId = setInterval(this.myTimer.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    myTimer() {
        alert('index: ' + this.i);
        this.setPostionM(this.i);
        this.i++;

        if (this.i >= this.pointsArray.length ) {
            console.log('stop myTimer');
            clearInterval(this._intervalId);
        }
    }

    setPostionM(key) {
        this.marker.setPosition(this.pointsArray[key]);
    }
}

class MockMarker {
    setPosition(array) {
        console.log('position: ' + array);
    }    
}

const mockMarker = new MockMarker();
const routeMarker = new RouteMarker(mockMarker, [[10.21, 70.13], [14.62, 56.71], [22.34, 67.26]], 0);

routeMarker.main();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works, but it does not move the map marker, I'll have to do something different in the code

Comment: You're welcome! If you won't be able to solve, what you want to do, create a well-structured and researched question about your problem and post it as a new question. ;)